Show a button below of tabs in Jetpack Compose
I need to show a button below tabs in Jetpack Compose (Android, Kotlin)I have a screen like so, but the button os not shown up.
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    var tabIndex by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val tabs = listOf("Accounts", "Documents")
    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex) {
            tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(text = { Text(title) },
                    selected = tabIndex == index,
                    onClick = { tabIndex = index },
                )
            }
        }
        when (tabIndex) {
            0 -> AccountsScreen()
            1 -> DocumentsScreen()
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)) // Pushes the button to the bottom

        Button(
            onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {
            Text("Change Master Password")
        }
    }
}


I cannot reproduce the issue, the Button is clearly visible when I run your code. Maybe you used enableEdgeToEdge() and the button is hidden behind the Android system's Navigation bar?

You might have given Modifier.fillMaxSize() to your AccountsScreen or DocumentsScreen, which could be causing the button to be pushed out of view. Instead, you can use a Scaffold to manage your layout properly. Here’s an example of how to implement it:
    var tabIndex by remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val tabs = remember { listOf("Accounts", "Documents") }

    Scaffold(
        bottomBar = {
            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(16.dp)
            ) {
                Text("Change Master Password")
            }
        }
    ) { paddingValues ->
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(paddingValues = paddingValues)
        ) {
            TabRow(selectedTabIndex = tabIndex) {
                tabs.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                    Tab(
                        text = { Text(title) },
                        selected = tabIndex == index,
                        onClick = { tabIndex = index },
                    )
                }
            }
            when (tabIndex) {
                0 -> AccountsScreen()
                1 -> DocumentsScreen()
            }
        }
    }

